# Codeigniter - Setting multiple Sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

I'm trying to set 2 sessions with:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('name', 'value');
```

But I can only set one. I've:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user['id']);
```

The first one works but the second never is setted.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

P.S.: I'm portuguese, I may have some grammar errors. Sorry for that.

Comment: do a test to confirm that $user['id'] really has a value.

Comment: I already did it. It has. I'm taking the values from my database:    
`$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email="' .       $email . '" AND password="' . $password . '"');`  `$user = $query->row();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `$user` is not an array, but an object:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user->id);
```

Answer (score 2):

> $this->session->set_userdata(array('logged_in' => TRUE, 'user_id'=> $user['id']));

Answer (score 1):

if `$user = $query->row_array()`:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user['id']);
```

if `$user = $query->row()`:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user->id);
```

**http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html**

if it still does not work, try this:

```
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $this->db->where('password',$password);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    return $query->row();
```

**** I'm bad in English.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the function properly.

From the [CI Manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user->id);
```

This is how you set all the session data.

Note that `$user` produces an object not an array. So your access is wrong. Otherwise you can use the `row_array()` function and access as above